# Applying Google Analytics (GA) with Sencha Touch 2.x.x Mobile Application

Tags: extjs, google-analytics, sencha-touch-2, google-analytics-api, sencha-touch-2.1

I am working with sencha touch 2.2.1. i wish to implement GA in my app. But, when i tried to create an account in GA, there were 2 options  **Website**  or  **Mobile App**  . First i choosed the Mobile app. section there were only options for Android and iOS. ( they were telling to download the SDK ). So i realized that its not what i want. so i choosed the website section. But there they are asking the website name and URL. What should i do..!???  I am really trapped !!!

So kindly anyone plz help me to move on the right path.

Any useful info regarding the topic will be so much helpful !!

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use ga.js from an installed mobile app use this GitHub project
https://github.com/ggendre/GALocalStorage